# Groups of Pemutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am having a difficult time with the following question:

Find a four element abelian subgroup of S5 and then write its table.

I am lost as to where to start. Do I arbitrarily choose 4 elements of S5 = (1,2,3,4,5)? Any assistance will help!

Comment: The elements of $\;S_5\;$ are **not** the digits $\;1,2,3,4,5\;$ but *permutations* on them. If you don't understand this then you better go back to the basics and read that carefully.

Comment: I understand that elements of S5 are the permutations of them.

Comment: Then why did you write what you did at the end of your question??

Answer (score 1):

Two examples giving two different (up to isomorphism) groups with four elements:

$$H:=\langle (1234)\rangle\;,\;\;K:=\langle (12)(34)\,,\,(13)(24)\rangle$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what are some abelian groups of order $4$ you know about? (There are only two.)

Try to realize them as subgroups of $S_4$. Consider cycles and disjointness.